# ionic2 keeping side menu open

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm working with ionic 2, and I have a ion-menu on the left side of the app, which keeps closing when I open the menu and touch to the page area.

I'd like to make it to keep opened and to close only when the user explicitly order to close it(via close button, or maybe swiping back, whatever). is there any option or workaround to doing like that?

**EDIT**:
I started with [ionic2-starter-sidemenu](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-sidemenu). when I run it, it looks like:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|           | <menuToggle button>                             |
|           |-------------------------------------------------|
|           |                                                 |
|           |                                                 |
|     /*    |                                                 |
| side menu |                                                 |
| toggled by|                                                 |
| menuToggle|           /* Content of each Pages */           |
|   button  |                                                 |
|     */    |                                                 |
|           |                                                 |
|           |                                                 |
|           |                                                 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

and when I click the page content area, the menu closes like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| <menuToggle button>                                         |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                             |
|                                                             |
|                                                             |
|                                                             |
|                /* Content of each Pages */                  |
|                                                             |
|                                                             |
|                                                             |
|                                                             |
|                                                             |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried reading documentation and searched ionic forum, but found nothing to resolve it.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please show us what you are trying to do and what is expected with the code snippets. Only verbose are not very helpful for the answers.

Comment: Check out the docs for the `MenuController` https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/MenuController/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick hack until they release an update:

First:
Remove `menuClose` from any of your current side menu buttons

Then in **app.component.ts** call the MenuController:

`constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController, public platform: Platform) {...`

```
...
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.menuCtrl.open();
    });
}
```

This does 2 simple behaviors that expose-aside-when did basically:

- opens the menu when the app is loaded
- prevents any nav buttons from closing the menu

Answer (score 2):

Hope this answer isn't too late. However ionic 2 now supports the [splitplane](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/split-pane/SplitPane/) that works exactly as you described. Its syntax is as:

```
<ion-split-pane>
  <!--  our side menu  -->
  <ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
  </ion-menu>

  <!-- the main content -->
  <ion-nav [root]="root" main #content></ion-nav>
</ion-split-pane>
```

[image]

Comment: Could not get it to work with Angular's `<router-outlet>`.

Comment: are you using the ionic 3/2 routing or angular 2/4 routing

Comment: angular routing, like I said. Ionic has the `ion-nav`, angular has the `router-outlet`.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works well for me:

```html
<ion-navbar >
  <button ion-button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title></ion-title>
  <ion-buttons start>
    <button ion-button (click)="func1()">
      <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button ion-button (click)="func2()">
      <ion-icon ios="ios-exit" md="md-exit"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop the menu from closing you can remove the `menuClose` attribute/directive in `app.html` ([here's a link to it in the reference project source](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-sidemenu/blob/master/src/app/app.html#L10))

i.e. this `menuClose` bit:

```html
<button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
```

Here's some more info on the [MenuClose](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/MenuClose/) directive, and note that you can close the menu programmatically too.

Also, depending on the [menu type](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/Menu/#menu-types) you're using, you may find the `reveal` works better than the default `overlay` mode.