# Ionic 2/3 - How to keep a side menu open until the user clicks on a given button?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, side-menu, ion-content

Is there a way to keep an Ionic 3 side menu open until the user clicks on a given button?

The default behavior is that a side menu closes itself when the ion-content associated with receives a click event.
I would like to override this behavior.

```
<ion-menu type="push" (ionClose)="execDirtyWay()" [content]="dahcontent">
    <!-- I need this menu to stay open -->
    <!-- Even if the user clicks on the below ion-content -->
</ion-menu>

<ion-content #dahcontent>
  <!-- my content is here -->
</ion-content>
```

I'm using a push menu that displays a list and I need my ion-content area to be clickable without closing the said menu.

My issue is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095593/ionic2-keeping-side-menu-open) but I found none of the answers to be satisfying.

For now, I found a **very dirty** way to kinda get what I need:

in the `ionClose` event of the menu, I reopen it ｡(*^▽^*)ゞ

Answer (score 0):

I just found [here](https://github.com/seanmavley/ionic2-sidemenu-tabs/issues/8) a *cleaner* way to achieve what I wanted:

As soon as I open my menu, if I set it to disable (`this.menuCtrl.enable(false, this.SHOPS_LIST_MENU_ID)`), it will stay open even if we click on the content area.

I'm studying the eventual side effects of this method.

**EDIT**: Apprently there are some issues when interacting with the content on the ion-content area but only on the browser. On mobile, it does work fine.